# "Bad Argument Unsupported/Invalid URLs:" when adding sharepoint Url to my QNA bot

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I Tried to add sharepoint url to QnA Maker but got "Bad Argument Unsupported/Invalid URLs:". 
I Tried with sharepoint list, excel and word document but same error for all urls

Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: are you manually creating the knowledgebase?

Comment: yes manually creating it.

Comment: try creating anchor tags e.g. <a href=""></a> in you answers

Comment: This is the content of the document whose url is being passed in QnA Maker->
``` 
Earlier->
Question 1 
Test question 1 answer is here
 
Now->
Question 1 
<a href=""> Test question 1 answer is here</a>  
```
But still the error is same.
Can you please give a sample question and answer which will work?

Comment: ok let me check if i have one

Answer (score 0):

Please create an excel (.xlsx) file with you questions and answers and try importing in your knowledgebase by 
`yourQnAServicePortal -> Settings->Click Add files` your excel file should contain the questions and answers in following format:
[image]

QnA maker service should automatically extract question and answers from your excel file and add to your knowledgebase.
you can include html tags in your answers and make sure to publish the knowledgebase after adding the file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for all the prompt replies but, Add a file is working. But I don't want to add new files again and again for new pairs.
So instead I want to add new pairs in share point url and on just refresh, new pairs should be trained in QnA. That is the objective.

Comment: to achieve this you can create a power automate flow, that get triggered when file is created or updated (i am not sure if trigger for 'file updated' exists). then there is a sequence of qna maker api calls to add file to the knowledgebase and publish the knowledgebase

Comment: Power automate flow is the later part. First thing is I am not able to extract pairs from url of share point.Need to resolve that first

Comment: ok, have you tried placing the excel file similar to the image, in SharePoint and checked if it's url works in Qna Maker KB?

Comment: is there a certain way to place file in share point ? similar to image. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: you could prepare file locally, and upload it in a SharePoint document library then the url of the file would be like: `[sharepoint site url]/[document library]/[file name]`

Comment: Ok will try that. Just one thing, can it show the same error if all permissions are not there?or Or it will show permission error?

Comment: O yes! completely overlooked it. since SP is an authenticated environment, Qna maker will not accept the url of the document stored in this. What you can do for this is to save document, in an Azure public blob upon document upload in sharepoint, then refer the url of blob in knowledgebase